# jQuery - show when hidden, hide when showed

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#browse").click(function(){
            $("#navbar-secondary").show();
            $("#navbar-secondary").removeClass('hidden').addClass('animated slideInDown');
            $(this).find("a").focus().blur();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is working fine, but I want also to have **hide()** action on `#navbar-secondary` when `#navbar-secondary` is showed.

Regards.

Comment: you can add `$(this).hide();`  after `$(this).find("a").focus().blur();` but since your anchor tag is part of $(this) then everything under it will be gone .

Comment: can you show us your html ?maybe we can help out in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about .toggle()

```
$("#navbar-secondary").toggle()
```

Comment: what's different between toogle() and hide()?

Comment: toggle() hide element when it is shown and show when it is hidden  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

Comment: but can I use `animated slideOutUp` or other animation from animate.css before hide `#navbar-secondary?`

Comment: but how to do this? `#navbar-secondary` will be hidden before animation starts.

Comment: you can get some knowledge from here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107374/discussion-between-mateuszji-and-nab).

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `.is( ":visible" )` and then use the `.hide()` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#browse").click(function(){
        if ( $( "#navbar-secondary" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
            $("#navbar-secondary").hide().addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $("#navbar-secondary").show().removeClass('hidden').addClass('animated slideInDown');
            $(this).find("a").focus().blur();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, but can I use `animated slideOutUp` before hide `#navbar-secondary`?

Comment: Now i found it's some CSS3 functionality but i'm not familiar with that. Anyway, i dont see a reason why it wouldnt work.

Comment: but how to do this? `#navbar-secondary` will be hidden before animation starts.